# enable delayed expansion doesn't work

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10, command-prompt

I am getting a weird error in my batch program. I think the problem is in enable delayed expansion, but the fix I apply doesn't work. This is my code:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 3) do (
   set ff=Firefox_45_0.0_%%x
   echo %%x
   firefox.exe -CreateProfile "%ff% %homedrive%%homepath%\Desktop\Firefoxes\Profiles\Firefox_45_0.0_%%x"


)
```

ff doesn't have any value, although I used delayed expansion. What could be the fix?

EDIT: command printed to console (I don't use @echo off)

```
   C:\Users\Home2\Desktop\Firefoxes\Versions\Firefox_45_0.0>(
set ff=Firefox_45_0.0_1
 echo 1
 firefox.exe -CreateProfile "!ff! C:\Users\Home2\Desktop\Firefoxes\Profiles\Firefox_45_0.0_1"
    )
```

What is funny is that it actually performs as expected, although it prints !ff! in the console.

Comment: you only *enable* delayed expansion, but don't *use* it. Delayed variables are referenced with `!var!` instead of `%var%`.

Comment: using !ff! just prints !ff!. Is it because my command uses quotes? How do you use !! when command requires quotes?

Comment: using your code, just replacing `%ff%` with `!ff!` works fine for me. If it shows `!ff!` literally, that should be a hint, you didn't `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. Check your current code.

Comment: I realized that although it prints !ff! to the console, the code behaves as expected. Not sure why. but it Works.

Comment: `it actually performs as expected, although it prints !ff! in the console.` yeah, I admit that's confusing. Shot into the dark: the command repetition is not yet "runtime", so the delayed expansion did not yet take place.

Comment: Command echoing happens when a line is parsed, so delayed expansion did not yet happen; delayed expansion occurs *afterwards* at run-time; that's why `!ff!` is printed; quotation does not change anything as quote-handling is also done while parsing...

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for clarifying it out to me. Btw, where did you learn about command prompt in such depth? Any particular book? I would also like to master it.

Comment: Lots of experimenting... and following this extremely useful post: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133)

Comment: on Win 10, I tested doesn't work: `md !ff!` literally made a dir called !ff! and then complained for the rest of the iterations that dir exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!ff!` fixes it, as delayed expansion uses exclamation marks instead of percent signs.
Delayed expansion mode doesn't change the percent expansion, it adds a new and better way for expansion.

Delayed expansion is disabled by default.
To enable it in a batch file use

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=Hello world"
echo !var!
```

**Attention:**
On the command line the command `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` has no effect at all.
You could enable it by starting a new cmd.exe instance with `cmd /v:on`

Comment: using !ff! just prints !ff!. Is it because my command uses quotes?

Comment: I'm on Win 10, and with `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` I also get !ff! instead of the expanded values.

Answer (score 1):

The delayed expansion did not work on Win 10 I tested, from command line.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
```

The code below worked (to answer the question), without delayed expansion:

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, 3) do (
   rem set ff=Firefox_45_0.0_%x
   echo Firefox_45_0.0_%x
   firefox.exe -CreateProfile "Firefox_45_0.0_%x %homedrive%%homepath%\Desktop\Firefoxes\Profiles\Firefox_45_0.0_%x"
)
```

Win 10 CMD doesn't allow changes to SETLOCAL on command line. OK for batch files:

> Delayed environment variable expansion is NOT enabled by default.  You
>   can enable or disable delayed environment variable expansion for a
>   particular invocation of CMD.EXE with the /V:ON or /V:OFF switch.  You
>   can enable or disable delayed expansion for all invocations of CMD.EXE on a
>   machine and/or user logon session by setting either or both of the
>   following REG_DWORD values in the registry using REGEDIT.EXE:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\DelayedExpansion

    and/or

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\DelayedExpansion
```

> to either 0x1 or 0x0.  The user specific setting takes precedence over
>   the machine setting.  The command line switches take precedence over the
>   registry settings.
>
> In a batch file the SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION or DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
>   arguments takes precedence over the /V:ON or /V:OFF switch. See SETLOCAL /?
>   for details.
>
> If delayed environment variable expansion is enabled, then the exclamation
>   character can be used to substitute the value of an environment variable
>   at execution time.

Comment: DelayedExpansion also works on Win 10, but you tried to use it on the command line. There you can't enable it with `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` only with `cmd /v:on`

Comment: This is not special for Win10, that's the behaviour since WinXP, at least. Normally, you don't want to change the default delayed expansion mode with the registry key, else you get unexpcted behaviour from many batch files, expecting that it's disabled at start

Comment: I was able to change on command line on XP & 8.1 Dell Laptop. On Surface Pro Win 10 doesn't work on command line; /v switch & registry hack works.

Comment: I assume, it's already enabled on your XP and 8.1 system, or try to disable it with `SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion` that should fail also

Comment: I don't think it was enabled by default. I do remember enabling via `setlocal` before setting variables in !! on command line. I've upgraded since, on Win 10 now, and defaulted with registry, so don't have to enable everytime.