# Using Set /p command with a for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm working on a simple batch file to save a text file for each JPG. The content of the txt file are input by user using set /p. For some reason when i used set /p with the for loop, the txt file did not show value input by user (it only shows: "ECHO is on").Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

```
for %%Q in (*v.JPG) do (
set /p meas= "enter value "
echo %meas%>"%%~nQ.txt"
)
pause
```

Comment: Use the `search` facility in the top bar to find references to `delayed expansion`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of delayed expansion in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

Magoo is right, Thank you! I had to use Enable delayed expansion, and then referto variables as !variable! and not %variable%. Unfortunately, there isn't documentation on Microsoft website on this issue, at least not on the 'set' command webpage.

Answer (score -1):

```
for %%Q in (v*.jpg) do ( set /p meas="enter value " && echo !meas! > %%~nQ.txt)
```

I tested this in just a cmd prompt but should work in a batch as well.

This will create a new file named `<filename>.jpg.txt` and will contain the value the user entered.

The key is to add && between `set /p` and `echo`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805476/enable-delayed-expansion-doesnt-work  Magoo was correct.  Not sure how it worked for me.  Must have been user error on my part.